# How to use computed property names in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, object

I am getting an error message `Object literal may only specify known properties, and '[channel]' does not exist in type '{ a: any; b: any; d: any; }'` when using computed property names with spread.

here's a snippet:

```js
const color = { a: 1, b: 1, d: 2 }


const func = (channel: 'a' | 'b') => {
  const { a, b, d} = { ...color, [channel]: 9 }
}
```

you can try it out yourself in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=33&pln=4&pc=24#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOMC8MDeMCGAuGAjADQwBG%20xMAJvgEwwC%20AUC6JLAGYCuYwaMACmAALbGDABTePgDk2GTAA%20MGaRkBKNAD5MTGHHDRMOEqRJUG-LADpbCZCQDaIsZPgBdfAE5GTBkA)

What am I missing here? or is it a known bug? if so what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really an odd error, if you don't want to add the extra variable like Automatico suggested you can set the type [working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOMC8MDeMCGAuGAjADQwBG%20xMAJvgEwwC%20AUC6JLAGYCuYwaMACmAALbGDABTePgDk2GTAA%20MGaRkBKNAD5MTGHHDRMOEqRJUG%20KAE8ADhJAcDiFOiwA6TwmQkA2iLFJeABdfABORiYGIA)

```
const color = { a: 1, b: 1, d: 2 }


const func = (channel: 'a' | 'b') => {
  const { a, b, d}: typeof color = { ...color, [channel]: 9 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why this is happening, but you should be able to hack around it by storing the channel data in a variable first.

```
const color = { 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 2 }

const func = (channel: 'a' | 'b') => {
  const incoming = {[channel]: 9}
  const { a, b, d } = { ...color, ...incoming }
}
```

Comment: I think that's because we 're creating a new object by spreading the object so the new object will not be typed as the object being copied